# Configuring a bridge interface with systemd-networkd

Tags: linux, networking, systemd-networkd

I'm attempting to create a bridge interface in [Clear Linux](https://clearlinux.org/) with systemd-network to ultimately use it for KVM.

I've attempted to create the following files as part of [this](https://major.io/2015/03/26/creating-a-bridge-for-virtual-machines-using-systemd-networkd/) guide:

#### /etc/systemd/network/br0.netdev

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

#### /etc/systemd/network/br0.network

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Address=10.0.0.3/16
Gateway=10.0.0.1
DNS=10.0.0.1
```

#### uplink.network

```
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

After rebooting, `brctl` seems to imply that the `eno1` interface is not properly wired up to `br0`:

```
bswinnerton@nuc7i3 /etc/systemd/network $ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.429f5774d8b6       no
```

Here's the output of `networkctl`:

```
bswinnerton@nuc7i3 /etc/systemd/network $ sudo networkctl
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     unmanaged
  2 br0              ether              no-carrier  configuring
  3 eno1             ether              routable    configured

3 links listed.
```

And the status of `systemd-networkd`:

```
bswinnerton@nuc7i3 /etc/systemd/network $ systemctl status systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-12-19 22:45:53 UTC; 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 253 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─253 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Dec 19 22:45:53 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: br0: netdev ready
Dec 19 22:45:53 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: Enumeration completed
Dec 19 22:45:53 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: br0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Dec 19 22:45:53 nuc7i3 systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Dec 19 22:45:53 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: eth0: Renamed to eno1
Dec 19 22:45:53 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: eno1: IPv6 successfully enabled
Dec 19 22:45:58 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: eno1: Gained carrier
Dec 19 22:45:59 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: eno1: DHCPv4 address 10.0.0.3/24 via 10.0.0.1
Dec 19 22:46:01 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: eno1: Gained IPv6LL
Dec 19 22:46:13 nuc7i3 systemd-networkd[253]: eno1: Configured
```

Have I misconfigured a file? For what it's worth, I've tried `sudo brctl addbr br0`, `sudo brctl addif br0 eno1`, and then `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd`, and everything works as expected, but that doesn't persist between reboots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for config files in `/lib/systemd/network/` or `/run/systemd/network`, it seems some other config file is matching your `eno1` interface and starts DHCP on it

Comment: You're a life saver, that's exactly what the problem was. I had a file in `/lib/systemd/network/80-dhcp.network` that was was conflicting. Renaming `/etc/systemd/uplink.network` to `/etc/systemd/80-dhcp.network` resolved the problem.